# How can I force Mathematica to not symbolically evaluate a function used for NMaximize without redefining it?

Tags: evaluation, mathematical-optimization

As per the title, consider the following trivial example:

```
f[x_] := (Print[x]; -x^2 + 10 x)
NMaximize[
 f[x], x
 ]
(* x *)
(* {25., {x -> 5.}} *)
```

Now, as the printed `x` shows, `NMaximize` (like many other similar functions) first symbolically evaluates `f[x]` looking for ways to make the maximization process more efficient (and in this case understanding without further evaluation where the maximum is).

This is of course very convenient in many cases, but there are instances where the symbolical evaluation of the function can be extremely computationally expensive so that this initial evaluation may take more time that it is required for the maximization itself.

The standard way to avoid this is to redefine `f` to accept only numeric inputs, as per `f[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[x]; -x^2 + 10 x)`, which works as intended.
This can however be inconvenient, for example in the case of functions with many inputs, or more complicated input patterns.

Is there an easier way to tell Mathematica to not try to symbolically evaluate `f`, and go straight to use numerical methods?

Comment: Might it be that a proper [method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) fulfills your goal.

Comment: @corey979 explicitly fixing a method does not prevent the symbolic evaluation of `f[x]`

Comment: Isn't it easier just to use `Block[{foo}, foo[x_?NumericQ] := f[x]; NMaximize[foo[x], x]]` as needed in each case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat like [wigg0t's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36100/wigg0t) in that it uses the pattern-matching of the evaluation sequence, `replaceIf[in, pat :> expr]` replaces the input `in` by `expr` if `in` matches the pattern `pat`:

```
ClearAll[replaceIf];
replaceIf[in_, (Rule | RuleDelayed)[pat_, expr_]] /; MatchQ[in, pat] := expr;
```

Usage:

```
NMaximize[replaceIf[x, _?NumericQ :> f[x]], x]
```

---

A possible alternative is to use the fact that `Equal` does not evaluate to `True` or `False` if an argument is symbolic:

```
NMaximize[If[x == 0 || x != 0, f[x]], x]
```

Comment: this however still requires to specify the form of the numerical input, and it's not that much shorter that just redifining the function locally in a `Block` or `Module` as per your previous comment. What about defining a wrapper that redirects the first evaluation and calls the function regularly after that? Do you think that would cause problems to `NMaximize` (or whatever other function)?

Comment: @gIS I don't think anything is shorter (or clearer) than `foo[x_?NumericQ] := f[x]`, with or without `Block`. It seems at the least you would have to use `NumericQ`, and given that, `foo` seems terse. It would be nice if there were an option to `NMaximize[]` that did what you wanted, but I don't think there is one. -- FWIW, I like the generality of `replaceIf[]`, which is a bit like a ``GeneralUtilities`Match[]`` that doesn't `Panic[]` when the pattern doesn't match. But my preferred method is the one you are seeking to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

You could wrap your function in a head that suspends evaluation.

```
ClearAll[suspend];
SetAttributes[suspend, HoldFirst];
suspend[expr_, {__?NumericQ}] := expr

With[{vars = {x}}, NMaximize[suspend[f[x], vars], vars]]
```